# jQueryUI Datepicker with Two Fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to tidy up all the little whizz-bangs on my website but using jQuery for everything. This would include using jQuery UI for the datepicker.

There are two instances of the datepicker, ArrivalDate and DepartureDate, and I need to dynamically set Departure Date to the day following the date that a user has just entered as ArrivalDate.
ie If the user has chosen 25 Dec as the ArrivalDate, DepartureDate should have 26 Dec as the default and all dates before 26 Dec should be disabled.

I've tried the help of several things I've found on StackOverflow and elsewhere but none of them seem to work for me. This is what I currently have:

```
$('#ArrivalDate').datepicker({
minDate: 0,
defaultDate: 0,
dateFormat: "d M yy",
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
onClose: function(dateText, inst){
    var d = $.datepicker.parseDate(inst.settings.dateFormat, dateText);
    d.setDate(d.getDate()+1);
    $('#DepartureDate').val($.datepicker.formatDate(inst.settings.dateFormat, d));
}

}),
$('#DepartureDate').datepicker({
minDate: "d",
defaultDate: "d",
dateFormat: "d M yy",
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
}),
```

but DepartureDate still treats minDate and defaultDate as '0'.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved pretty easily, here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dwaddell/Q2kkG/

```
onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
        var d = $.datepicker.parseDate(inst.settings.dateFormat, dateText);
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
        $('#DepartureDate').val($.datepicker.formatDate(inst.settings.dateFormat, d));
        $('#DepartureDate').datepicker('option', {
            minDate: $.datepicker.formatDate(inst.settings.dateFormat, d)
        });
    }
```

Also you may want to check out the API here http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate, you might want to use setDate instead of val on the line before my change.  Or maybe both.